# How to apply OpenCV filters on Pytorch dataset?

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch

I have used below steps to pre-process single image using OpenCV. Now, I want to apply these pre-processing steps to my entire dataset before training the model in Pytorch. How can this be done?

```
im = cv2.imread(image_path)
im_nonoise = cv2.medianBlur(im, 3)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im_nonoise,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
cl1 = clahe.apply(imgray)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(cl1,110,255,0)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
img = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (250,100,120))
```

And I load the data using

```
data = datasets.ImageFolder(train_dir,transform=transform)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data,batch_size=batch_size,sampler=train_sampler)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own dataset class (derived from `ImageFolder`) and overload only the `__getitem__` method:

```py
class MySpecialDataset(datasets.ImageFolder):
  def __init__(self, root, loader=default_loader, is_valid_file=None):
    super(MySpecialDataset, self).__init__(root=root, loader=loader, is_valid_file=is_valid_file)

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    image_path, target = self.samples[index]
    # do your magic here
    im = cv2.imread(image_path)
    im_nonoise = cv2.medianBlur(im, 3)
    imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im_nonoise,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
    cl1 = clahe.apply(imgray)
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(cl1,110,255,0)
    image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    img = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (250,100,120))
    # you need to convert img from np.array to torch.tensor
    # this has to be done CAREFULLY!
    sample = torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()(img)
    return sample, target
```

Once you have this dataset, you can use it with the basic pytorch's `DataLoader`:

```py
data = MySpecialDataset(train_dir)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data,batch_size=batch_size,sampler=train_sampler)
```

Comment: In here you will need to import `from torchvision.datasets.folder import default_loader` also. @Shai I am unable to use this as there are also other parameters like batch_size and sampler(i have used SubsetRandomSampler) which generates error. I tired `class MySpecialDataset(datasets.ImageFolder, batch_size,sampler):
  def __init__(self, root, loader=default_loader,batch_size=batch_size,sampler=sampler, is_valid_file=None):
    super(MySpecialDataset, self).__init__(root=root, loader=loader, batch_size=batch_size,sampler=sampler,is_valid_file=is_valid_file)`

Comment: Used above as `train_loader = MySpecialDataset(data, batch_size=batch_size,sampler=train_sampler)` but it generates error `NameError: name 'sampler' is not defined`

Comment: @Blueberry this class does *not* replace your loader, but rather your dataset.

Comment: Thanks @Shai solved my problem :) Made some changes to include `transform` too. Thanks for your help.